# Get "Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error when I run wiremock.jar on MAC

Tags: java, slf4j, wiremock

How about the case of running WireMock in the terminal with java -jar wiremock-standalone.jar? Shouldn't console logging be enabled?

Steps:

1. I downloaded the jar from: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone/2.9.0/wiremock-standalone-2.9.0.jar
2. Run it and got the error:
   [image: error screenshot]
3. Check my java version and upgrade to the latest, but no help:
   [java upgrade, but no help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEZSd.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me that you're trying to start the specific class in a standalone manner. This won't work as WireMock depends on a lot of other classes/jars that are not part of this jar.

For this reason a seperate Stand alone version is released which can be downloaded here [Maven Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone/). Instructions on how to start this version can be found here [WireMock userguide](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/).

When starting the standalone version a standard error is shown that causes no functional issues:

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> ```

In order to remove this error download [slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.9/slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar) and place it in your class path. Alternatively put it next to your WireMock jar and adjust your command to this:

**Windows example**

```
java -cp "slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar;wiremock-standalone-2.15.0.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --port 9999 --global-response-templating
```

**Mac example**

```
java -cp "slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar:wiremock-standalone-2.15.0.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --port 9999 --global-response-templating
```

In your screenshot I see that you're running 2.9.0, whereas the current version is 2.15.0. I recommend upgrading wiremock to this version.

Comment: Thanks Kootstra, but looks still fail:      MacBook-Pro:Wiremock Alpha$ java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.14.0.jar
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
...

Comment: At [SO] we use comments to ask for clarifications on the given answer/question and use the corresponding [edit] functionality to update an answer or question. Can you please update your question with what you've tried, including code/command examples, and what you've observed?

Comment: Updated the answer to provide context and resolution for the issue.

Comment: Thanks Kootstra, works. But on MAC, should change ; to :

Comment: Created seperate examples for both Windows and Mac. If this is the solution to your issue, please mark this answer as the solution for others who have this problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works even with extension jar I write. Set my entrypoint to `java,-cp,libs/${wiremock.jar}:libs/${extension.jar}:libs/*,${wiremock.main.class},--extensions,${extension.class},....` and I see logs in console.

Comment: In case someone had same issue on Virtualbox Debian, replace the ; with :

java -cp "slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar:wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.32.0.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --port 9999 --global-response-templating